# Process crashes on second message in Erlang

Tags: erlang, shadowing

I have a simple car process implemented in Erlang:

```
-module(cars).
-compile(export_all).

-record(state, {count=1}).

make_car() ->
  spawn_link(fun() -> car_proc(#state{}) end).

car_proc(S) ->
    receive
        {idle, X} ->
            io:format("idling for ~p second(s)~n", [X]),
            timer:sleep(X*1000);
        {move, {X,Y}} ->
            io:format("move; x=~p, y=~p~n", [X,Y]);
        {stop, Reason} ->
            X = S#state.count,
            io:format("stopped with count ~p because ~p~n", [X+1, Reason])
    end,
    X = S#state.count,
    car_proc(S#state{count=X+1}).
```

I can make it idle, but if I call idle twice in a row, it breaks:

```
59> C = cars:make_car().
<0.207.0>
60> C!{idle,1}.         
idling for 1 second(s)
{idle,1}
61> C!{idle,1}.         
idling for 1 second(s)
{idle,1}
62> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 9-Apr-2013::00:00:00 ===
Error in process <0.207.0> with exit value: {{badmatch,2},[{cars,car_proc,1,[{file,"cars.erl"},{line,20}]}]}

** exception error: no match of right hand side value 2
     in function  cars:car_proc/1 (cars.erl, line 20)
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs on line 20, which is

```
X = S#state.count
```

It occurs because the pattern matching fails. The variable 'X' is already defined in this line and it's value is 1, because it has been determined in receive block:

```
receive
        {idle, X} ->
```

In Erlang value of variable can be defined only one time. When you send message {idle, 1} first time X becomes 1 and default value of S#state.count is 1. So in that case 'X' matches S#state.count. When you send {idle, 1} second time X is 1 and S#state.count is 2 (i.e. X and S#state.count are not equal). So you get error in pattern matching. You can use another variable to avoid the problem. Change two last lines

```
X = S#state.count,
car_proc(S#state{count=X+1}).
```

to

```
Count = S#state.count,
car_proc(S#state{count=Count+1}).
```

and be happy!